# Bump Map - 2.80

Tags: modeling

I realize that Blender 2.80 is still in beta and that bump map painting stems way before this version, but I'm definitely having a difficult time finding any detailed tutorial on how to set it up. I want to do what this person is doing but he's doing it in an earlier version and doesn't explain the set up so that I can bump map paint. Any help with the appropriate steps would greatly be appreciated.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDN4Wwl6EOY&t=33s

Answer (score 0):

Heres a tutorial I found. It's from 2013 but should work about the same now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGRG2nXPmQY